# How i can save integer value with button click without intent

Tags: android, onclick

So how i can store this "Heitot" integer. After clicked "Seuraava" button it should be ("Heitot" + current amount" + plus click) so it should store all button clicks.

here is picture what i mean [Here is picture before clicked "Seuraava"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUmNB.png), [Here is picutre after clicked "Seuraava"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRTRC.png)

Here is code from my viewholder:

```
public class PlayListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Teams> {

private GoPlay activity;
private TeamDatabaseHelper teamDatabaseHelper;

public PlayListViewAdapter(GoPlay context, int resource, List<Teams> scores, TeamDatabaseHelper helper) {
    super(context, resource, scores);
    this.activity = context;
    this.teamDatabaseHelper = helper;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
    if (convertView == null) {
        // inflate UI from XML file
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_list_items, parent, false);
        // get all UI view
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        // set tag for holder
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // if holder created, get tag from view
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Teams score = getItem(position);

    holder.listItemText.setText(score.getPlayerName());
    holder.parItemText.setText(score.getCurrentPar());
    holder.totalParText.setText(score.getTotalPar());
    holder.currentParText.setText(score.getScorePlusMinus());

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView listItemText;
    private TextView parItemText;
    private TextView totalParText;
    private TextView currentParText;
    private int count;
    private String strcounter;


    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        listItemText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
        parItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.parIndexTextView);
        totalParText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.totalparTextView);
        currentParText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.plusMinusTextView);


        Button minusBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.minus_btn);
        Button plusBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.plus_btn);

        minusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
                count--;
                strcounter = Integer.toString(count);
                parItemText.setText(strcounter);
                totalParText.setText(strcounter);
            }
        });
        plusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
                count++;
                strcounter = Integer.toString(count);
                parItemText.setText(strcounter);
                totalParText.setText(strcounter);

            }
        });

    }
    }
```

}

And here is my "Seuraavabutton click"

```
public void onNextBtn(View view) {
    Intent intent;
    if (stageCount + 1 < gameDatabaseHelper.getHolesCount(null)) {
        stageCount += 1;
        centerTitle.setText("Väylä " + (stageCount +1));
        reloadingDatabase();

    } else {

        intent = new Intent(GoPlay.this, ScoreMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? You have not specified it.

Comment: I had question how i can store that text. My issue is i dont know how to save it. @VirRajpurohit

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to store it and fetch anytime you open up that screen.

You can use **SharedPreferences** available in Android.

```
//To save
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("COUNT",YOUR_COUNT);
editor.commit();

//To retrieve
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
int snowDensity = settings.getInt("COUNT", 0); //0 is the default value
```